# Build all possible phrase pairs from a sentence pair

Tags: java, beginner

I have an array for an English sentence (`enSentence`) and for a German sentence (`deSentence`). Each value represents one word. I want to print every possible phrase pair (`enPhrase` and `dePhrase`), where no phrase contains more than `maxhPhraseLength` words. A phrase can consist of a single word, all words of the sentence, and everything inbetween (consecutive).

So for `Hello world !` and `Hallo Welt !`, possible phrase pairs would be:

- `Hello` - `Hallo`
- `Hello world` - `Hallo`
- `Hello world !` - `Hallo`
- `world` - `Hallo`
- `world !` - `Hallo`
- `!` - `Hallo`
- …
- `Hello` - `Hallo Welt`
- `Hello` - `Hallo Welt !`
- `Hello` - `Welt`
- …
- `Hello world !` - `Hallo Welt !`

But phrases like `Hello !` or `world Hello` are *not* possible.

This is my first try:

```
enLoop:
for(int en1 = 0; en1 < enSentence.length; en1++) {
  for(int en2 = en1; en2 < enSentence.length; en2++) {

    if(en2-en1+1 > maxPhraseLength) {
      continue enLoop;
    }

    deLoop:
    for(int de1 = 0; de1 < deSentence.length; de1++) {
       for(int de2 = de1; de2 < deSentence.length; de2++) {

         if(de2-de1+1 > maxPhraseLength) {
           continue deLoop;
         }

         // building the phrase pair
         enPhrase = "";
         dePhrase = "";
         for(int e = en1; e <= en2; e++) {
           enPhrase = enPhrase + " " + enSentence[e];
         }
         for(int d = de1; d <= de2; d++) {
           dePhrase = dePhrase + " " + deSentence[d];
         }
         enPhrase = enPhrase.trim();
         dePhrase = dePhrase.trim();
         System.out.println(enPhrase + " - " + dePhrase);

       }
     }

  }
}
```

I’m interested in any kind of feedback (I rarely create code from scratch).

I considered naming the variables language-neutral (in case I want to use the code for making phrase pairs in other languages, too), but couldn’t come up with something short and catchy (`sourceSentence`/`source1` and `targetSentence`/`target1` are longer, and I always have to remind myself what the source and what the target is, while it’s immediately clear to me if thinking about the terms `en`/English and `de`/German instead; but the difference doesn’t really matter in this case anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Repeating work

You should move all of the code that computes `enPhrase` to before the `deLoop`.  There is no need to recompute `enPhrase` each time you modify `de2`.

Furthermore, when you compute `dePhrase`, you can do so by appending the next word `deSentence[de2]` to the current `dePhrase`.  Right now you reconstruct all of `dePhrase` in the inner loop, making it an \$O(n)\$ operation when it could be an \$O(1)\$ operation.

#### Get rid of loop labels

You can get rid of the loop labels if you precalculate the proper end of the loop.

#### Use StringBuilder

It's more efficient to use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings rather than using the `+` operator.

#### Rewrite

Here is a rewrite showing the above changes:

```
StringBuilder enPhrase = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder dePhrase = new StringBuilder();

for(int en1 = 0; en1 < enSentence.length; en1++) {
  int en2Max = Math.min(enSentence.length, en1+maxPhraseLength);
  for(int en2 = en1; en2 < en2Max; en2++) {
    if (en2 == en1) {
      enPhrase.setLength(0);
    } else {
      enPhrase.append(" ");
    }
    enPhrase.append(enSentence[en2]);
    for(int de1 = 0; de1 < deSentence.length; de1++) {
       int de2Max = Math.min(deSentence.length, de1+maxPhraseLength);
       for(int de2 = de1; de2 < de2Max; de2++) {
         if (de2 == de1) {
           dePhrase.setLength(0);
         } else {
           dePhrase.append(" ");
         }
         dePhrase.append(deSentence[de2]);

         System.out.print(enPhrase.toString());
         System.out.print(" - ");
         System.out.println(dePhrase.toString());
       }
     }

  }
}
```